# Unable to connect to PC via SSH from Android

Tags: windows, ssh

I use Windows 7 on my Desktop. I tried to connect my Android to my PC via Wi-Fi connection. SSH port 22 is open on my desktop. I use [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) to connect to my PC.

The result of `ipconfig`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>­ipconfigWindows IP ConfigurationEthernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : domain.name
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::286c:2b76:ae18­:18f5%14
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::6e72:20ff:fe7d­:1063%14192.168.0.1
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnectedConnection-specific 
DNS Suffix . :Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:Connection-specific 
DNS Suffix . :Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::79f7:d7d6:8a1f­:4c13%11
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.25
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
C:\Windows\system32>
```

From ConnectBot via SSH:

```
Connecting to 192.168.0.2:
The authenticity of host '
lished.
Host EC key fingerprint is
:6c:de:6c:f6:c0:78:2a
Key exchange was not finis
The server hostkey was not
allback

Connection Lost
```

Ping result from Android:

```
app_30@android:/ $ ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.13 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=1.45 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=1.49 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=1.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=1.40 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=10 ttl=128 time=1.37 ms
```

The connection works with **USB** and the problem is for **WIFI** only.

Comment: Im sure. The connection works with USB

Comment: You're trying to SSH into a Windows machine? Do you have Cygwin or some other SSH server running on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes , I do have one

Comment: What's the full error message? The one you posted above appears to be cut off (*server hostkey was not*) Have you tried a SSHing using putty or some other SSH client from the Windows machine itself to ensure the server is set up correctly?

Comment: I tried its working. But not with putty. I have ssh binaries installed . I can connect my android ( connectbot) via USB the problem is only for WIFI